# How do I avoid the connection manager breaking in SSIS?

Tags: sql-server, ssis, connection-string

I made some changes to the connection manager yesterday, using SQL Authentication instead of Windows authentication. But today for some reason all the connections had red x's whene I opened them. Then I reverted back to using Windows authentication and the same issue persisted. I had to go into each object and re-add the connections.

I'm using an OLE DB connection that is being used as a project connection.

Also when I'm transferring a single package to someone else. For some reason he is unable to view and use the connection manager? Any reason why this could be and how I can solve it.

Comment: What is your package protection level set to?

Comment: I have both the Package and Project saved as Don'tSaveSensitive

Comment: Is the other person granted access in AD to that particular connection? Seems obvious but worth enquiring